# Datareceive from more than one device

Tags: c#, string, serial-port

I have a small problem. Now I have written my code, and it works excellent, but I'm trying to do it better.
I receive data from a device, but now I will upgrade it to receive data from more devices. 
To this I have made a string called adress, this is the string which should be looked at. If this string is for example 111222333, then the data received should be saven in chart 1. But if this string is for example 333aaa444, then the data received should be saven in chart 2.

```
    private void port_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            recievdata = SerialPort.ReadExisting();
            string adress = recievdata.Substring(7, 16);

            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));

            using (Stream stream2 = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append))
            using (StreamWriter sWriter1 = new StreamWriter(stream2))
            {
                if (adress )
                if (recievdata.Contains("UCAST") && recievdata.Contains("=g"))
                {
                    sWriter1.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                    sWriter1.Write(" ; ");
                    sWriter1.WriteLine(1);

                    if (SleepMovChar.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        SleepMovChar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                        { SleepMovChar.Series["Bevægelse"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), 1); }));
                        SleepMovChar.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Hope that you can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the chart 1, chart 2 or the checks for the different values that you mentioned in your question text.  What is the actual problem that you are having?

Comment: My problem is, how I write the code, when I actually want to differentiate between more "adresses". I know that I havn't made the other chart, but it's not my problem.

Comment: The fact is, that I don't know the address before I receive it in my serial port. Therefore, I'm not sure, how to say, if the address is still the same, do this else do something else.